# Graphics2D How to draw color in grayscale?

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, grayscale

I see you can convert BufferedImage objects to grayscale.  But can you set a mode to make your graphics draw 'primitive' lines, arcs, rectangles etc only in grayscale even if you've setPaint() to a non gray color?

What I'd like to do is this:  Our drawing methods will have access to a mode flag.  If this mode flag is true, then everything should be drawn in full color.  If it's false then everything should be drawn in shades of gray derived from their color representation.  The gray version should indicate that it is disabled.

We'd like to avoid loading and using images, and would prefer to just draw things for various reasons.

Comment: A possibility would be a custom [Composite](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Composite.html) for the gray scaling. Whether that can actually used depends... swing cheats and `Graphics2D.setComposite()` does not work except for `AlphaComposite` for swing back buffers, because of missing raster methods, but it works if you're drawing to a buffered image, for example.

Comment: I was thinking of wrapping all my calls to setPaint().  I think we only use 2 kinds of Paint objects -- Color and GradientPaint.  So I could just translate the colors in those Paint objs to grays if mode was false, and then call the real setPaint().

Answer (score 0):

Create new BufferedImage with colorMode, copy all content to him and save it with

Example:

```
BufferedImage grayImg = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
BufferedImage colorImage = new BufferedImage(grayImg .getWidth(), grayImg .getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D graphics = colorImage.createGraphics();
graphics.drawImage(grayImg ,0,0,null);
graphics.dispose();
grayImg.flush();
ImageIO.write(colorImage ,"jpg", newPath);
colorImage .flush();
```